# Assembly - length of string

Tags: assembly, nasm

Wht this code print the str? As far as I know len should be defined as `$-len`

```
section .data
str: db 'I am a program',0ah,0
len: dd len-str
section .text
global _start
_start:
mov edx,[len]
mov ecx,str
mov ebx,1
mov eax,4
int 0x80
```

Comment: Why do you think that `len` and `$` are different in that line?

Comment: In general, `length = end - start`.  Turns out my answer on the linked duplicate actually has an example of using `$-start` vs. `end-start`.